# Xcode 6.1 iPad simulators versus Xcode 5.1.1 iPad simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I built most of my app in Xcode 5.1.1.  Xcode 5.1.1 had iPad simulator and iPad retina simulator for iOS 7.1. Last week i downloaded Xcode 6.1. Xcode 6.1 simulators are iPad 2, iPad Air, and iPad retina.

1)From Xcode 5.1.1, does iPad Retina match the same simulator as iPad 2 from Xcode 6.1?

OR

2) Apple has iPad Air2, iPad Air, iPad mini 1,2 and 3. Is iPad retina and iPad 2 the same iPad as iPad mini only Xcode 6.1 calls it iPad Retina and iPad 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference. iPad is non-retina and iPad air and iPad retina are retina. Whatever you coded in the iPad simulators in Xcode 5.1.1 will transfer over to Xcode 6.1 iPad simulators retina and non-retina

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification for I already found out long ago. I'll still give you best answer even though it's 2 months late but at least you answered and it is the correct answer.